# github- only newest commit showing

Tags: git, github, repository, git-commit

I recently opened my first GitHub account, to be able to easily share my code when applying for internships. I taught myself how to do it, so here are the commands I've been using, in GitBash (Windows):

```
cd "folder name"
git init
git add *.cpp
git commit -m "xyz"
git remote add origin https://github.com/myUserName/myRepositoryName.git
git remote -v
git push -f origin master
```

After each one I check to see that it has appeared on GitHub, and add a README to explain the code. I did this for a number of files before I realized that only the latest commit and its README are being shown in my repository...
My GitHub account says I have 35 commits, but I can only see the most recent 2.
The files all have different names, so I don't think they are being overwritten. Also, the email in GitBash does match the email in my GitHub account, so I don't think that's the problem.
It may be something obvious, because I'm very new to this, so any help would be very much appreciated!
I'm hoping I don't have to start over again, because it did take some time...Thanks :)

Comment: did you do *all* these commands in different folders?

Comment: Why do you use `git push -f`? With force-push you override your commits.

Comment: I used the force-push because when I was playing around with it and trying to figure it out, I initialized the repository with an empty README, and so the pushes to github weren't working....This is how I got it to work...Oh no :( So there's no way to retrieve those commits? Is my best solution to just create a whole new repository and start again, this time doing a regular push each time?

Comment: And can I follow the same above commands, but just not do the force-push?